# Generic Num class

Tags: c++, c++11

How do you create a generic num like class so that the only thing that matters is that the relevant member function/operator exists?

I've read up on [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) but I don't get it to be honest.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Numeric {
  const T a;
public:
  Numeric(const T &v) : a(v) {}

  T operator+(const Numeric<T> &b) {
    return a + b.a;
  }
};

int main() {
  Numeric<float> fl1(35.5);
  Numeric<float> fl2(10.5);
  Numeric<uint64_t> i64(10000);
  std::cout << (i64 + fl1 + fl2) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here, `fl1 + fl2` would be fine but since the operator definition says `T` is the same type `i64` can't be mixed with `fl1` or `fl2`.
Are templates the right thing here, would it be better to use the object hierarchy defining a top level `Num` for e.g. that defines all the operators and have a sub class for each supported type? Though I don't think that solves the mixing types problem.

*EDIT 1:*
Background in res to Barry/lisyarus: 
I'm changing an old code base which has a type defined like this:

```
template<typename a> struct NumT : public SomeSuperType<a> { mp::cpp_int val;};
```

The change is to add support for native `float` and `double` types in this `NumT` type in a transparent a way as possible.
Ideally NumT shouldn't change beyond changing the decl. type of `val`.
Existing code just does `a + b` and other arithmetic operations on `val`, not breaking the existing API stuff is important.
`i64 + fl1 + fl2 == 10046`

Comment: What is the probably you are trying to solve by `Numeric<T>` that isn't solved by just `T`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Or, what should be the type of `i64 + fl1 + fl2`? Whether it is `int64` or `float`, it is lossy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a reason why numeric types are different (`int`, `float` and so on), trying to commonize them can get awry. Nonetheless, you can use [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) to deduce the type that can contain both.

Mind you there will be a loss of *"precision"* here.. For example, if you have an `unsigned long long` of `1434263462343574573ULL`, converting it to `double` will lose some significant digits.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Numeric {
    const T a;
public:
    Numeric(const T &v) : a(v) {}
    T get() const { return a; }
};

template<typename T, typename U>
Numeric<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type> //With C++14, do std::common_type_t<T, U>
operator + (const Numeric<T>& a, const Numeric<U>& b) {
    return a.get() + b.get();   //Works because of the converting constructor
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Numeric<T>& n){
    os << n.get();
    return os;
}

int main() {
    Numeric<float> fl1(35.5);
    Numeric<float> fl2(10.5);
    Numeric<uint64_t> i64(10000);
    std::cout << (i64 + fl1 + fl2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This prints:

```
10046
```

Comment: I see, nice. I didn't know about `std::common_type`. I'll stay wary of the precision issue

Comment: _"There's a reason why numeric types are in classes"_ What do you mean by this?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I meant there's a reason why we have different numeric types, e.g `int`, `float` etc... I've reworded the statement now.